# What tree is it? (orange/yellow Jacaranda?)

Tags: identification, trees

It looks very similar to Jacaranda, which I have in my garden, but the flowers are orange (and see another similar trees with yellow flowers).

Couldn't find its name, is it from the same family of Jacaranda? The same but with different color?

(If that matters, it's in Israel)

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the flowers that you can see in closeup at the lower left of the second picture, I think it is a Delonix regia, Royal Poinciana or also called a "Flame Tree". This would be in the bean family.

The purple flowers of Jacaranda are sort of different in structure, more tubular like a snapdragon or a trumpet. Botanists have put these two trees in completely different families, but the leaves are amazingly alike.

Both trees are simply spectacular when they are blooming!

Comment: Thanks! And they really do! My street is full of Jacarandas and there's one also in my parents garden, and it's amazing when it's blooming.

Comment: There's also a very similar one, which is yellow - is it from the same family of this one?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Gulmohar tree to me. Also known as Flame Tree, Royal Poinciana and its scientific name is Delonix Regia.
It's found all over India and known for it's fern like leaves and bright flaming red-orange flowers that bloom in spring and last for the summer.

Comment: Hi there, can you add a little more detail to this?